# Exiting while loop with sentinel in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, sentinel

So I've just created a simple program to try using sentinel controlled while loops in Python 3.7. When the user inputs the sentinel value however, the loop does not end. I can't seem to find the issue in my code.

```
print('Welcome to the WiFi Connection Wizard, here are some troubleshooting steps:')

SOLVE= 'no'

while SOLVE != 'yes' : 
    print('\nPlease reboot your computer and then try to reconnect.')
    SOLVE= input('Did this solve your problem? Plase type "yes" or "no": ')

    print('\nPlease reboot your router and then try to reconnect.')
    SOLVE= input('Did this solve your problem? Plase type "yes" or "no": ')

    print('\nPlease make sure the cables between the router and modem are securely plugged in.')
    SOLVE= input('Did this solve your problem? Plase type "yes" or "no": ')

    print('\nPlease try moving the router to a different location.')
    SOLVE= input('Did this solve your problem? Plase type "yes" or "no": ')

    SOLVE = 'yes'
```

When the user enters yes, the loop continues for some reason. Am I missing something? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what the user enters in the code you posted; it will always prompt four times, then ignore the user's responses and set `SOLVE` to `'yes'`, then promptly end the loop. If you want to break earlier, you need to test `SOLVE` after each time you set it; the `while` condition is only tested when the body of the loop ends (or you `continue`) and it loops back to the top. Your loop isn't actually accomplishing anything here.

A possible solution is to explicitly test after each `input`:

```
while SOLVE != 'yes' : 
    print('\nPlease reboot your computer and then try to reconnect.')
    SOLVE= input('Did this solve your problem? Plase type "yes" or "no": ')
    if SOLVE == 'yes':
        break

    print('\nPlease reboot your router and then try to reconnect.')
    SOLVE= input('Did this solve your problem? Plase type "yes" or "no": ')
    if SOLVE == 'yes':
        break

    print('\nPlease make sure the cables between the router and modem are securely plugged in.')
    SOLVE= input('Did this solve your problem? Plase type "yes" or "no": ')
    if SOLVE == 'yes':
        break

    print('\nPlease try moving the router to a different location.')
    SOLVE= input('Did this solve your problem? Plase type "yes" or "no": ')
    if SOLVE == 'yes':
        break

    SOLVE = 'yes'
```

But the `while` is still pretty pointless; all it does is make it easier to skip the remaining tests, and you have a ton of repeated code.

A more useful loop structure would be to loop over a set of prompts, so you don't duplicate any code at all, and the loop structure provides more than just a way to skip subsequent tests, it helps structure your code for better readability and reduced boilerplate:

```
prompts = ('\nPlease reboot your computer and then try to reconnect.',
           '\nPlease reboot your router and then try to reconnect.',
           '\nPlease make sure the cables between the router and modem are securely plugged in.',
           '\nPlease try moving the router to a different location.')
for prompt in prompts:
    print(prompt)
    SOLVE= input('Did this solve your problem? Plase type "yes" or "no": ')
    if SOLVE == 'yes':
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the for loop suggestion with the prompts. However this is a textbook exercise and it says to not use the if --- break structure and to only use a sentinel. My confusion comes from why this example code works but mine doesn't:

Comment: @tarruda23: I have no idea what the example code *is* so I can't say why it works (it might be for a problem where sentinel tests make more sense). If `if`/`break` is prohibited, it likely wants some terrible reimplementation of `for` loops using a `while`, where the `while` can test for the sentinel and for running out of prompts on each loop. But I can't say for sure without knowing how many hands you've been told to tie behind your back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're expecting the loop to terminate after any of the `SOLVE` prompts, right? e.g. If the user reboots their computer and then tries to connect, and they type `yes` after the first step, the loop should terminate?

The condition in the `while` loop only gets evaluated after ALL the contents of that block have finished running, and Python is deciding whether to run the entire block another time. Your code doesn't really make sense as written. A minimal sentinal-controlled loop might look like the following:

```
print('Welcome to the WiFi Connection Wizard, here are some troubleshooting steps:')

SOLVE= 'no'
while SOLVE != 'yes' :
    print('\nIs it magically working now?')
    SOLVE= input('Did this solve your problem? Plase type "yes" or "no": ')
```

The program will loop forever until the user types `yes`, at which point is will stop.

I'm not sure a while loop makes sense for what you're trying to do here. I would write this more like the following:

```
print('Welcome to the WiFi Connection Wizard, here are some troubleshooting steps:')

messages = [
    'Please reboot your computer and then try to reconnect.',
    'Please reboot your router and then try to reconnect.',
    'Please make sure the cables between the router and modem are securely plugged in.',
    'Please try moving the router to a different location.'
]

for m in messages:
    print('\n{}'.format(m))
    solve = input('Did this solve your problem? Plase type "yes" or "no": ')
    if solve == 'yes':
        break
```